# Why does pandas attempt to import a module when reading from a pickled file?

Tags: python, pandas, pickle, instagram-api

I have collected some data via the Instagram API, which I've stored into a pandas DataFrame, which in turn has been saved via pandas `.to_pickle()` method.

When attempting to load the DataFrame on another computer using the `read_pickle()' method, the following error is returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "examine.py", line 14, in <module>
dataframe = pd.read_pickle(args["dataframe"])
File "/home/user/virtualenvs/geopandas/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pickle.py", line 65, in read_pickle
return try_read(path)
File "/home/user/virtualenvs/geopandas/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pickle.py", line 62, in try_read
return pc.load(fh, encoding=encoding, compat=True)
File "/home/user/virtualenvs/geopandas/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/pickle_compat.py", line 117, in load
return up.load()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
dispatch[key](self)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1090, in load_global
klass = self.find_class(module, name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1124, in find_class
__import__(module)
ImportError: No module named instagram.models
```

Any idea what causes this?

Comment: Is any of the data saved in the pickle contain objects of that type? Could you show df.head() and df.dtypes.

Comment: Based on `ImportError: No module named instagram.models` it is likely that inside the `DataFrame` there are objects which are from the `instagram` model. You will be able to check this by inspecting the data types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pickle simply doesn't know how to recreate the classes. The information how a class is unpickled and restored is stored inside the class: `__new__`, `__init__`, `__setstate__` and more.

> **Similarly, when class instances are pickled, their class’s code and data are not pickled along with them. Only the instance data are pickled.** This is done on purpose, so you can fix bugs in a class or add methods to the class and still load objects that were created with an earlier version of the class. If you plan to have long-lived objects that will see many versions of a class, it may be worthwhile to put a version number in the objects so that suitable conversions can be made by the class’s `__setstate__()` method.

Source: [Python pickle: What can be pickled and unpickled?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled)

So to unpickle it, `pickle` needs to load the class (and thus any intermediate module).

If you don't have/want the `instagram`-module you should check how to convert the appropriate values in your original dataframe to normal classes (`int`, `float`, `array`, ...) before you pickle it.